# Rest API filter quote

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, query

I am using the *SharePoint rest API*, I need to **quote a string in the filter query**.
This is my query:

```
?$filter=MyField eq 'aaa'aaa'
```

How can I search the string " aaa'aaa "?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two quotes. That is for `'aaa'aaa'` use `'aaa''aaa'`

Comment: This also works in other areas of the REST API, such as checking in a file with single quotes in the comment.